# How to send a notification to an offline app whenever there is an online transaction

Tags: php, mysql, server-push

I want to send a notification to an offline client application, and also update the offline database whenever there is transaction on the web application.
The client application has a static IP address issued by my ISP.

How should I do this?

Secondly, there may be cases when there is no internet access on the offline app, how would I request for, or resend any transaction done online to the client when the internet access on the client is restored?

I use `PHP` and `MySQL` on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to send data between applications. It depends on the client application interface.

If it is web application you can use HTTP protocol and appropriate data format (XML,json,csv). You can use simple HTTP request or on of the standards(REST, SOAP).

For standard network application listening on some IP port you can use socket.

If you have mysql database on both sides, you can set-up replication of database data.

Be aware of sync problems in case that offline application also modifies data.